# Flip Results using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Good morning,
It has been quite some time since I coded in VBA. I have the below chart (pic number 1) which I need flipped like pic number 2. New months will be added on in the future so I need to be able to account for that. Next month will show April, each following the same format as the first chart. So on and so forth.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Define the range to flip and then walk that range, checking for blank cells to the left of each cell. If one is found, set the value of the leftmost blank cell to the left to the value of the cell being checked and then clear the current cell.

Comment: Thank you frank. You wouldn't be able to provide an example by chance would you? it's been years since I've coded VBA .

Comment: Give it a try and if you get stuck, let us help you.  But first, you need to put in some work....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
Sub MyTest()
Dim a, w, i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, m As Long, n As Long

a = Range("B2:F6").Value

For i = LBound(a) To UBound(a)
    w = Application.Index(a, i, 0): k = 1: m = 0: n = 0
    For j = LBound(w) To UBound(w)
        If w(j) <> Empty Then
            a(i, k) = w(j)
            k = k + 1
        Else
            n = n + 1
        End If
    Next j
    If n > 0 Then
        For j = UBound(a, 2) To LBound(a, 2) Step -1
            m = m + 1
            a(i, j) = Empty
            If m = n Then Exit For
        Next j
    End If
Next i

Range("B10").Resize(UBound(a, 1), UBound(a, 2)).Value = a
End Sub
```

Comment: That's way over-complicated....

Comment: @FrankBall I think so too. Waiting for others to contribute to learn from their approaches.